# RTSP link not support in iphone12 by VLCKit 3.3.17 pod

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoa-touch, rtsp

My RTSP url is suitable for all iPhone except iPhone 12 series with MobileVLCKit framework.

below iPhone12 it's works fine with MobileVLCKit libraries.
but in iPhone12 i found

"Unable to determine our source address: This computer has an invalid IP address: 0.0.0.0"

this
and
live streaming not play in MediaPlayer.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: let url = URL(string: "rtsp://192.168.0.1:554/livestream/1")

if url == nil {
return
}
let media = VLCMedia(url: url!)
mediaPlayer.media = media
mediaPlayer.play()
mediaPlayer.libraryInstance.debugLogging = true

Comment: MovileVLCKit version 3.3.17